# How to convert Number of hours into number of work-hours days in postgreSql?

Tags: postgresql

i have a column which has data in "12:19:04" this format. 
i.e 12 hours 19 min and 4 sec.
i want to convert this into number of days considering working hours as one day i.e 10 hr

so the above time should be displayed as 1 day 2 hr 19 min and 4 sec

and also if the hours value is too huge then month days hours and minutes should be displayed.

Kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: Use epoch time, divide by 10 days in seconds, convert remainder back to seconds.

```
WITH s(secs) AS (SELECT extract(epoch from interval '12:19:04'))
SELECT justify_interval(
         floor(secs / 36000) * INTERVAL '1' DAY 
       + (secs::integer % 36000) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
) FROM s;
```

Comment: i created this function but it is nly giving the seconds part and not displaying anythin "00:00:04" nly this as output am getting.

Comment: @user3243383 Well, without seeing the *input*, I can't tell you anything about the *output*. The second query is much better btw, don't use the first one.